# Будет ли pyc файл запускаться под разными версиями интерпретаторов?

Tags: python

Допустим, у меня python 3.2, я скомпилирую свою программку в pyc файл и, например, захочу кинуть её другу, но у него стоит python 2.7. Будет ли программка у него запускаться?

Answer (score 2):

могу немного ошибиться за все версии python не ручаюсь, но в каждой версии python стоит своя версия компилятора и при попытке импорта модуля скомпилированного другой версией python вылезает ошибка: bad magik number 
     с ней сталкивался довольно давно на версиях python до 2.5
    как обстоят дела сейчас не знаю

Answer (score 0):

Смотря как она написана на 3.2...у них есть различия в некоторых командах.я так думаю..)а проще взять и попробовать ))

Ну либо себе еще 2.7 установить и попробовать через нее запустить файл, написанный на 3.2=)